# Web view- web page is not displayed

Tags: android

I have created a web view in android activity
my any code has no error.
but when it run it is trying to open in google chrome.

here is the my code

```
public class MyCustomListView extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_custom_list_view);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

and xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.87" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and log cat show this
 should not happen no rect based test nodes found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because, the url is being redirected. You can use the WebViewClient to achieve this.

> webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
>
> ```
>         @Override
>         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
>             view.loadUrl(url);
>             return true;
>         }
>     });
> ```